# pytorch net creation does not generate weights if done in a list

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm creating a net in pytorch by writing a class called MyNet with **init**() and forward() method.
If I create a layer in **init**() like:

`self.fc = nn.Linear(5, 10)`

everything works fine and

```
net = MyNet()
paramL = list(net.parameters())
```

gives me a list with some weights inside.
However, if I create layers in the following way

```
self.layerL = [nn.Linear(5,10)]
```

something seems to go wrong, since list(net.parameters()) now gives an empty list :-(

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ??

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, this is because it is not a `torch.nn` object.
For this use `torch.nn.Sequential`. For example,

`self.Layer = torch.nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(5,10), nn.Linear(10,10), ...)`

Comment: What I really want is to give the constructor of my class a list like [20,10,3] and then it should build a net consisting of three fully connected layers with 20, 10 and 3 nodes. I.e. I need a way to create the layers without knowing in advance how many there will be. How can I do this without putting the layers in a list !? And for some reasons I would like to use the class method and not Sequential. Is that possible ? -- Or do you mean I should place the Sequential call inside my class constructor ?!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found a solution here
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-create-mlp-model-with-arbitrary-number-of-hidden-layers/13124

Basically, I have to register the layers with the module.